# Uniform convergence of series of arccosines

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\arccos{{n^4x^4}\over{1+n^4x^4}}$$ supposedly converges uniformly on any interval $I$ for which $0\notin\overline{I}$ while
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\arccos{{n^2x^2}\over{1+n^2x^2}}$$ does not converge at all for any $x$.

Firstly, how should I go about proving this? The derivatives of the summands don't seem to converge... If there were say $\arctan$ instead of $\arccos$, I could use $|\arctan x| \leq |x|$... If there were other terms, I could use the boundedness... But I don't know how to estimate the arccosines... Moreover, can $I$ really be unbounded? What if I chose $x_n = {{1}\over{n}}$...

Thank you.

Comment: You can use $\cos x = 1- \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \dotsc$ to find $\arccos (1-\varepsilon) = \sqrt{2\varepsilon} + \dotsc$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a>0$ and let's prove the uniform convergence of the first series on $[a,+\infty)$. Let

$$g_n(x)=\frac{n^4x^4}{1+n^4x^4}$$
then by the derivative we get easily that $g_n$ is increasing and then $f_n=\arccos(g_n)$ is decreasing then

$$||f_n||_\infty =f_n(a)$$
Moreover, we have

$$\cos(f_n(a))=g_n(a)\sim_\infty 1-\frac1{x^4 n^4}\implies f_n(a)\sim_\infty\frac{\sqrt2}{x^2n^2}$$
and since the series $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent so the given series is uniformly convergent on $[a,+\infty)$.